# Do the wattage from connected devices need to add up with the given wattage from a step-down converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, watts, step-down

A step-down buck converter converts 36V to 12V 36W.
Does it mean that the sum of all the wattage from all connected devices need to be 36W? **OR** Does it mean that I can connect multiple devices not producing more than 36W power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that I can connect multiple devices not producing more than 36W power?

It means you can connect multiple devices not **demanding** more than 36 W of power in total.

Some switch-mode converters may behave badly (be more noisy, or allow output voltage to drift up) if the load is much lighter than they are designed for. If your load is less than, say, 25% of the designed capability of the converter, you should check on the performance with light load before selecting that converter.

Comment: I think you might want to make it clear that it is the total power (the sum of the power) from all the devices that can't consume more than 36W of power.  At the moment, reading his answer and your answer, it appears that you are referring to "each device individually not demanding more than 36 W of power"